# ionic 4 side menu doesn't update it's content

Tags: ionic4, side-menu

I have created an ionic 4 app.

- I am using native google maps and custom marker.
- When I click on a marker, I want to open my side-menu with place details.

What I did,

```
- I have disabled the menu at first on app.component.ts
- When ionViewWillEnter() on Map Tab, I have disabled the side-menu
- When ionViewWillLeave() on Map Tab, I have disabled the side-menu
- Side-menu only will enable when to click on the place marker
- I have triggered the event when clicking on place marker
- This event carries the data of place
- I have used the variable 'business' to fill the side-menu
- I have subscribed the event on app.component.ts and assign the 
place data to 'business' variable
```

Problem:-

- My side menu doesn't update it's content when I click on the marker
- It updates when I switched between tabs, I think when refreshing the tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the data of 'business' variable updated?
If so, perhaps you could try run the assignment code inside ngzone.

```
// import zone in your app.component.ts
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
// add zone provider to the component constructor
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
   // ...
  }

// cath click event, then
this.zone.run(() => { 
// update data here
});
```